# svn: database is locked, executing statement 'RELEASE s0'

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I keep getting the error listed blow in attempting a merge from a private branch:

> database is locked, executing statement 'RELEASE   s0'

I run collabnet subversion edge server: 1.7.5-3220.94

I run the tortoise svn client: TortoiseSVN 1.7.7, Build 22907 - 64 Bit , 2012/05/15 12:16:05

Can anyone please point me to what's causing this, and how to resolve this. The references on the Web suggest some process is using the sqlite backend. The generic "Release lock" action from svn client contextual menu doesn't seem to help?

Comment: This may mean that your working copy is accessed by another client at the same time.

Comment: But I usually ensure that I've closed down all tortoise SVN client windows except the window I'm using to initiate the merge?

Comment: Run cleanup using break write locks. It should work.

Answer (score 12):

If you're on Windows version just let's do the next:

Right click on the repo folder and go to `TortoiseSVN` options and next to this select the option `Clean Up`.

In clean up's options select:

```
Clean Up working copy status
Refresh Shell Overlays
Include external
```

sho

Comment: Thanks, I had tried Clean Up without "Refresh Shell Overlays" checked and that was not sufficient - checking that box allowed Clean Up to do the right thing and unblock my Merge/Reintegrate command.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I was using Tortoise and Eclipse at the same time. Closing Eclipse resolved this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have this problem since so long and it was because I had Netbeans open when doing update.

Answer (score 7):

I got this error when I tried to update local copy but merge window was left open. I closed the merge window and update and cleanup worked correctly.

Answer (score 6):

If I open a shell and run a subversion command then try to merge using Tortoise I get this error.

Closing the shell window and then doing the merge again from Tortoise it works.

Comment: I had to kill the svn process in the shell too.

Answer (score 6):

IF you use another program (netbeans) , you have configure the program Netbeans :

options > Team > versioning > subversion > Preferential client 
Alter this option for "CLI", and after select the SVN.exe in the dir TortoiseSVN\BIN

this resolve the problem the locked database

Comment: This helps, and is quicker than restarting Netbeans.

Answer (score 3):

Do SVN clean up. Problem will be resolved.

Comment: Actually it is not resolved. Being over-confident ruins credibility. Better to allow for the possibility there can be difference causes/solutions for the same symptoms in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a friend that got stuck with this. He restarted his computer and everything went fine, nothing lost and he could work again.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens because another program is performing version control on the same working copy.

Close the program (Eclipse, Netbeans, ...), and try again, after performing a "Clean Up" on the working copy

Answer (score 1):

If nothing work from the above answers then just kill the process from task manager and try it again. **No need to restart.** It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I think it's likely a case that my working copy had local modifications.
I just skimmed through TortoiseSVN 1.7  By: Lesley A. Harrison which recommends that to ensure a smooth merge:
ensure your working copy is clean and has no local modifications. I think this wasn't the case in my instance.

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

use  lsof  to list  svn's file handle  and kill it   then run svn cleanup

Answer (score 0):

This helped me solve the problem (subversion 1.7.10):

```
 $ cd /my/repository/.svn
 $ mv wc.db wc.db.old
 $ sqlite3 wc.db.old
 sqlite> .backup main wc.db
 sqlite> .exit
```

After making sure it works, you can remove wc.db.old.

Comment: You should upgrade to the latest SVN 1.9.x

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the first thing to check is if any other "svn update" is in progress or not. If yes, either wait for it to finish or kill it(if you killed it, you will need to run "svn cleanup"). After this, svn should behave normally.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. For me, it was because **the project folder was inside OneDrive** and OneDrive was syncing the same folder. When I **stopped syncing OneDrive and closed it**, things were resolved.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows 2008 R2, a OS restart fixed it.