# E200033: Another process is blocking the working copy database

Tags: svn, ubuntu-16.04

When I checkout from repository

```
sudo svn co --username me http://192.168.1.27/svn/project
```

I got the this error and checkout process terminated

```
svn: E200033: Another process is blocking the working copy database, or the underlying filesystem does not support file locking; if the working copy is on a network filesystem, make sure file locking has been enabled on the file server 
svn: E200033: sqlite[S5]: database is locked 
svn: E200042: Additional errors: 
svn: E200033: sqlite[S5]: database is locked
```

I am unable to get checkout or update for this project (no cleanup, update, etc command working after getting error).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Follow the below steps:

```
 $ cd /my/repository/.svn 
 $ mv wc.db wc.db.old 
 $ sqlite3 wc.db.old 
 sqlite> .backup main wc.db
 sqlite> .exit

Afterwards, do a svn cleanup.
```

[svn: database is locked, executing statement 'RELEASE s0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500954/svn-database-is-locked-executing-statement-release-s0/45816582?noredirect=1#comment78605383_45816582)

Comment: The command ".backup main wc.db" resulted in :"Error: databse is locked" for me.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Tortoise-SVN, sometimes it can go brain dead and the caching functionality gets stuck.  Go into Task Manager and kill all instances of TortoiseSVN-Cache and try again.

Comment: This was it for us; we have the client installed on a build server that is wound in an extremely tight loop for checking for modifications and every so often we'd get this error. Because we did not care about Icon Overlays we disabled them completely for the build server.

Comment: For me it helped killing instances of both TSVNCache.exe and TortoiseProc.exe

Answer (score 14):

Close all the files opened in the editors and run the clean up. It fixed the issue for me. I closed my Netbeans and executed the clean up command.

Comment: yes, closing netbeans solved the issue for me. Even when the project was closed from netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

The internal working copy SQLite database is blocked (its in your working copy's hidden metadata pristine store: `.svn/wc.db` file). I'd start with checking your user account permissions. There is a great chance that you lack write access to the checkout target location.

It could be another SVN client instance that's by some reason is still running tasks with the WC. An antivirus or indexing service could also be the root cause -- it is a general recommendation to add antivirus and indexing exceptions to ensure that these tools do not touch the working copies.

Comment: How to deal with it? Any solution? @bahrep
BTW, I am using Ubuntu, no need antivirus client

Comment: @RaveeSunshine *permissions*

Answer (score 1):

Simple SVN clean up worked for me !!

Answer (score 0):

are you using matlab? if yes, go to preference->general->source control then select no.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to checkout into a networked drive, and had this issue. Once I moved my target checkout location to somewhere local, this issue disappeared. Then I could just copy the files into the networked location where I wanted them.